# Tigervnc server ignores configuration file

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, tigervnc

I am using `tigervnc 1.6.0` on Slackware 14.2. According to [the documentation](http://tigervnc.org/doc/vncserver.html) I should be able to place a file in `$HOME/.vnc/config` and define some settings I always want to apply, thus eliminating the need to pass them on the command line every time I start the VNC server.

My config file looks like this:

```
$ cat .vnc/config
SecurityTypes=None # do not ask for a password
```

However, when I call

```
$ vncserver :1
```

the setting gets ignored. I still have to explicitly define the setting on the command line:

```
$ vncserver :1 -securitytypes none
```

I also tried to place the configuration file in the other locations mentioned in the documentation (`/etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-defaults` and `/etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-mandatory`) without success.

Are there any additional steps I need to take to make `vncserver` respect the settings in the configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a Ubuntu 17.10 container with tigervnc and it seems to rely on a file `/etc/vnc.conf` for defaults, you can override parameters by creating a file called `~/.vnc/vnc.conf` using a perl syntax for example:

```
$geometry="1920x1080";
```

I hope this helps. I'm running VNC 1.7.0

```
# dpkg -l | grep vnc
ii  tigervnc-common                 1.7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu1               amd64        Virtual network computing; Common software needed by servers
ii  tigervnc-standalone-server      1.7.0+dfsg-7ubuntu1               amd64        Standalone virtual network computing server
```